# Can a husband and wife to look each other's thights?

Tags: nikah, husband-wife, awrah, husband

The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Do not uncover your thigh, and do not look at the thigh of the living and the dead.Can a husband and wife to look each other's thights?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. You should add a source for your claim also note that there's no 'awrah between spouses [What is the 'awrah between husband and wives?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46393/what-is-the-awrah-between-husbands-and-wives) and you may find answers for this on the site.

Comment: a gust gvve tis answer at the question https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/in-islam-are-there-limits-on-sex-between-a-married-couple#1358?newreg=55aaabf61ff840bdae0f934b6a391030
"Since there is no direct hadith related to it, it should be safe to do it" - but there are some hadiths: islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37135/… and some indirect ayats that might be used: 7:20-22. – qdinar Feb 25 '17 at 1:46
@qdinar why did you put this answer. Does it goes also for a married people?

Comment: so..is it that an interpretation only of @qdinar?

Comment: I've so far not come across any scholarly opinion saying otherwise and of course scholars say one should have in mind that we should respect our Creator. You may read my answer on qindar's post and find that firstly scholars have different opinions on the thigh being 'awrah secondly the hadith doesn't say a wife can't look at her husband's 'awrah and vice versa it is a general statement and accepts legal exclusions.

Comment: @Medi1Saif otherwise the qdinar opinion?

Comment: is the Qdinar interpretation wrong for the scholars?