# Can husband and wife take shower together and they can see their naked body?

Tags: halal-haram, husband-wife, ghusl

I want to know that in islam,
Husband and wife can bath togethers and they can see their naked body and love each other like this way ?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please consider using meaningful and related tags this way you will easily get duplicate or related posts and answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the 'awrah between husbands and wives?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46393/what-is-the-awrah-between-husbands-and-wives)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised how unaware Muslims are these days of Sharia. Heck yes, if you can be intimate with each, then looking at each other is of a lesser level.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu alaikum brother, not onlyhusband and wife bathing together and watching each other naked is completely valid but they can touch each others private part also. As long as they do not kiss each others private parts.
Allah knows best